# How can I make the following slider using slick/swiper/or any other plugins or raw code?

Tags: jquery, slick.js, uislider

[This the photo of the slider. I need to make a slider like this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtNjj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/3d-card-rotator-carousel-slider.html). Not exactly like the image but I guess you can make changes.

Comment: Links are welcome as references, but the key steps should still be summarized in the answer to make the answer self-contained. Link-only answers may get deleted.